# How to sort a loop order using linq query in C#?

Tags: c#, linq

Assume that I have a list of items from 1 - 3.

I could order them by 1,1,2,2,3,3.

But instead, I would like to order them by 1,2,3,1,2,3....

Is there an already exist function to achieve that?

Comment: No, there isn't. I can't even name this kind of sorting in one or two words. You can implement it yourself.

Comment: This might be technically possible using LINQ alone, but it would be messy. It would be far cleaner and more efficient to implement it yourself.

Comment: Makes no sense. What if it is `1,1,2,2,3,3,3,3,4` what would the output be? Out of the box Linq provides implementations which are common such as order or order by descending. What would this ordering be? Looks like a very specific case

Comment: @CodingYoshi then it should be like 1,2,3,4,1,2,3,3,3

Comment: Why? How come it's not 1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,4 and the other possibilities

Comment: @CodingYoshi Why would the output be that? That makes even less sense than the result he gave. Not only does the advancement to 4 seem entirely arbitrary, it doesn't even have the same number of 1's, 2's, and 3's in the sample input you gave and are (presumably) using.

Comment: @CodingYoshi according to your input, i have no idea how can you get that kind of input?

Comment: @chitkhine well that's my whole point. There is no logic to how to arrive at the output so yes mine makes no sense either because i dont know what the output should be.

Comment: @ChitKhine is you input list is sorted?

Comment: @CodingYoshi Except your output doesn't match your input at all. Your input was `1,1,2,2,3,3,3,3,4` and if I sorted your output it would get `1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4`. Not only are there different counts of each number, but the number of *elements* doesn't even match (the output magically gained an element).

Comment: @ChitKhine imagine your items are in array called `arr` then do this: `var result = Enumerable.Range( arr.Min(), arr.GroupBy(x => x).First().Count() )
            .SelectMany(y => arr.OrderBy( x => x ).Distinct().ToList());`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This approach separates each number into groups, then iterates through the groups in order while conditionally adding them to a result list. There's probably ways to make this safer and more efficient, but this should give you a start. (It assumes that if there aren't equal counts of each number in the source array, it will skip those numbers as it runs out of them during the iteration phase.)

```
int[] arr = new[] { 1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,5,5,5 };

var orderList = arr.OrderBy(x => x).Distinct().ToArray();
var refList = arr.GroupBy(x => x).ToDictionary(k => k.Key, v => v.Count());

var result = new List<int>();
int i = 0;
while (result.Count < arr.Length)
{
    if (refList.Values.Sum() == 0)
        break;

    if (refList[orderList[i]] > 0)
    {
        result.Add(orderList[i]);
        refList[orderList[i]]--;
    }

    i++;
    if (i >= orderList.Length)
        i = 0;
}

// Result: [1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5]
```

Comment: I generally got the idea. I will try it out for myself since 1,2,3 is just a type of the objects that I have.

Comment: or potentially: `var result = Enumerable.Range( arr.Min(), arr.GroupBy(x => x).First().Count() )
            .SelectMany(y => arr.OrderBy( x => x ).Distinct().ToList());`

Comment: @CodingYoshi That assumes that A] the numbers in the source list are guaranteed to be in sequential order, and B] the counts of each number in the source list are guaranteed to be equal.

Comment: A] No. B] Yes. But it can easily be changed. But the OP accepted your answer so perhaps that is what he was after :)